# JSP doesn't see JavaBeans

Tags: eclipse, wildfly

everybody!
Can't solve this problem:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: JBWEB004062: Unable to compile class for JSP:

***JBWEB004060***: An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file: /indexJB.jsp
packt.book.jee_eclipse.ch2.bean.LoginBean
***cannot be resolved to a type***

- 11: <%if ("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())&&
- 12:
  request.getParameter("submit")!=null)
- 13:      { %>
- 14:  <jsp:useBean    id="loginBean"
- 15:
  class="packt.book.jee_eclipse.ch2.bean.LoginBean">
- 16:
  <jsp:setProperty name="loginBean" property="*"/>
- 17:  </jsp:useBean>

I use:
WildFly 23
Eclipse Version: 2021-09 (4.21.0)

**What I found in Internet:**
**Note**

See the detailed error message under More Information.

​This issue occurs because JBoss EAP 6.2 server runtime is using unsupported JDK. Verify the following log statements for reference:

java.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin

java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment

java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_20-b26

**Solution**
​To resolve this issue, do as follows:

1. Point your JBoss EAP 6.2 server to a supported JDK that is JDK 1.7.x
   (best is 1.7.0_25).
2. Restart the application server.

**But how to point???**

Thanks in ADVANCE!

The whole code is here:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W#C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<%  String errMsg = null; %>
<%if ("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())&&
        request.getParameter("submit")!=null)
        { %>
    <jsp:useBean id="loginBean"
    class="packt.book.jee_eclipse.ch2.bean.LoginBean">
    <jsp:setProperty name="loginBean" property="*"/>
    </jsp:useBean>
    <%
    if (loginBean.isValidUser())
    {   out.println("<h2>WElcome, Admin!</h2>");
        out.println("You are logged in");
    }
    else
        errMsg = "Invalid user ID or password!";
        }   
    %>

<body>
<h2>Login:</h2>
    <%if (errMsg!=null ) {%>
    <span style="color: red;"><%out.print(errMsg); %> </span>
    <%} %>
    <form method="POST">
    User Name: <input type="text" name="userName" style="color: Green; background-color: Yellow"><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" style="color: Yellow; background-color: Silver"><br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved:

Right click on project-> choose properties -> Java Build Path -> choose third marker Libraries -> put cursor on Classpath -> on right menu choose Add Class Folder -> choose folder for classes -> Apply and Close.

I also restarted Eclipse just in case.

And my JSP finally sees Java Beans!

Hope that will help=)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).